# npm update the /dist/example.js (minified) file without having the source files (from CLI)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-publish, npm-update

I have a npm package that and I've built a custom version from and I only changed 1 file from the build files `/dist/example.js`.

Can I keep updating my own version of the package to npmjs.com without having the source files and rebuilding it? So I'd only publish the compiled minified code.

I've tried to build my own npm package and publish it but I couldn't update it.

So my final question is:
How could I update an existing npm package's `dist/example.js` file from **npm CLI**?

Thank you.